# publish the values ​of the HC-SE04 MQTT ESP8266 "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]"

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt, esp8266

I'm writing code to do monitoring, I'm having trouble transforming the calculated distance values ​​into const char* to publish it in mqtt. What can I do to solve my problem? I've already tried using sprintf but got no results.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h> 
 
#define TOPICO_SUBSCRIBE "..."   
#define TOPICO_PUBLISH   "..."  
#define ID_MQTT  "..."     

const char* ssid = "..."; 
char* password = "...";   
char* BROKER_MQTT = "broker.hivemq.com"; 
int BROKER_PORT = 1883;
 
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient MQTT(espClient);
```

```
const int trigPin = 2;  //D4
const int echoPin = 0;  //D3

long duration;
int distance;
 
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  init_serial();
  init_wifi();
  init_mqtt();
}
```

Here starts my problems (I cut snippets of code to be able to publish)

```
void loop() 
{   
    verifica_conexoes_wifi_mqtt();    
    MQTT.publish(TOPICO_PUBLISH, "ESP32 se comunicando com MQTT");   
    MQTT.loop();
   
    delay(1000);   

    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    
    // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    
    // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    
    // Calculating the distance
    distance= duration*0.034/2; 
    char msgDistance;
    msgDistance = distance;
    sprintf(msgDistance,"A distância lida é: ", distance);
    MQTT.publish(TOPICO_PUBLISH, msgDistance);
}
```

Comment: `char msgDistance;` defines the `msgDistance` variables as a *single* character. How would it fit a full string like you try to `sprintf` into it?

Comment: You declare `distance` as an int. Then you do `distance = duration*0.034/2` which is assigning a double to an int. And finally you do `msgDistance = distance` which is assigning an int to a char.

Answer (score 0):

The problems with this code are how it stores the result of the distance calculation and how it uses `sprintf` to format the message you want to transmit.

First, you defined `distance` as an `int`, which really isn't going to work with this line:

```
    distance= duration*0.034/2;
```

You're doing floating point math. If you store the result in an `int`, you'll lose any fractional value of the result. If the result was less than 1, it would end up being 0.

You also declared it to be a global variable but there appears to be no need for it to be global. It's better to limit its scope by only making it available where it's needed. In this case it looks like you can move both `distance` and `duration` inside `loop()`, so you'd remove their definitions before `setup()` and write them inside `loop()`:

```
void loop() {
  long duration;
  float distance;
```

Your `sprintf()` code currently looks like this:

```
char msgDistance;
msgDistance = distance;
sprintf(msgDistance,"A distância lida é: ", distance);
```

There are several problems with this:

- `sprintf()` needs to take a character array pointer as its first argument. Instead, you're passing it a single character variable. This makes no sense and is generating the compiler error you're seeing.
- `sprintf()` needs a format string to tell it what to print (written as `%X` where `X` is a character indicating the type of data being printed. You included some text but no format string.
- `sprintf()` can very easily overflow the `char` array it's printing into; you should use `snprintf()` instead

To solve the first problem, we need `msgDistance` to be an array of characters: `char []`.

Your code needs to look more like this:

```
char msgDistance[32];

snprintf(msgDistance, sizeof(msgDistance), "A distância lida é: %0.2f", distance);
```

The changes are:

- `msgDistance` is now a character array that `snprintf()` can use
- deleted the unnecessary assign to `msgDistance`, which would cause an error now that it's a `char` array
- `snprintf()` is the safer form of `sprintf()` - it takes the length of the character array as an argument so that it can't accidentally overflow the array
- `sizeof()` is a built-in function which returns the size of a variable at compile-time; it's an easy way to use the size of the array here but beware it may not do what you expect if you don't really understand C/C++ arrays and pointers and strings
- `%0.2f` in the `snprintf()` format string - this tells `snprintf()` to print a `float` variable (that's the `f`), with a leading zero if needed (that's the `0` part and two decimal places of precision (that's the `2` part - if you wanted one decimal place you'd write it as `%0.1f`)

You can learn more about `printf()` format strings using a search engine; there are many good tutorials and references for them available online.